# Initial pull from GitHub in Visual Studio

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2015

I have a stupid question. I created a project and then had a local backup. At some point I started working on the backup and then created a `Github` repository from that.

Now I want to pull that "backup" from `Github` to my original project and start working from the correct location again. (It's even dumber when I write it down).

The problem I am having, being new to `Github`, is that my original project can't pull from `Github`. It seems like `Visual Studio` is asking me to first create a new repository for that project before being able to do anything.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Do you have any changes on your main project? Can you not just remove it completely and checkout the project again from github?

Answer (score 0):

What I'm guessing you're saying is how can I download [my github repository] -- which you can do like this:

`$ git clone "********insertGithubRepoNameHere*********"`

If you're saying "how do I create another branch to my project" then all you'd need to do was go to your Github repo, click the Branch button, and enter you branch name: [Image of the Branch button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSOqN.gif)

If I've misinterpreted your question in any way please inform me promtly so I may correct it.

Comment: Where should I type that line ($ git clone...)?

Comment: I don't mean to be a brat but.. ``$`` is not part of the command, and also I found this: [https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/](https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/). Also I think @ROHITH has got it

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize a git repository and add a remote to your original project .
To do that ,go to command line and navigate to your project

```
 c:\projects\myproject> git init
```

(You can do this from Visual studio as well) .Under the right most corner of VS,click Add to source control and select git (image below)

[image: Add to source control in VS]

Now in command line ,add your GitHub URL as remote origin and do a pull

```
 git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

Now you have two repositories setup.One your local and other is your remote which is from GitHub.Now you can emrge these two with a command

```
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

The above command merges both repos from origin to master branch. If you get any merge conflicts,you have to resolve that.

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer. When I typed in "git init" it said "Reinitializing existing Git repository" so it was there. Next I followed you steps and typed "git remote add origin.." and got the error "remote origin already exists". Makes sense. So I tried to pull with the following command "git pull "https://username:password@github.com/username/repo.git" and it returned "command not found" "warning: no common commits" but then when I clicked "enter" it looked like it was getting all the files but nothing has changed in the actual project.

Comment: --allow-unrelated-histories needs to be added for merging.Which version of git are you using?

Comment: could you also post the output of the command.You may have got conflicts while doing merging.The same files are present in both repos and causing conflicts.